# discord.py (rewrite) How do I make a command to a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to make a command that is narrowed to only a specific channel. It sends a random picture of a car, but I have a channel called 'Pics' that i specifically need to narrow the command to. Can you help me out?

```
@client.command()
async def car(ctx):
    pictures = [
    'https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/78294/la_auto_show_11.jpg',
    'http://www.azstreetcustom.com/uploads/2/7/8/9/2789892/az-street-custom-gt40-2_orig.jpg',
    'http://tenwheel.com/imgs/a/b/l/t/z/1967_firebird_1968_69_70_2000_camaro_blended_custom_supercharged_street_car_1_lgw.jpg',
    'https://rthirtytwotaka.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/dsc_0019.jpg',
    'http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/fluke27.jpg',
    'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pCt0KXC1tng/maxresdefault.jpg',
    'https://i2.wp.com/www.tunedinternational.com/featurecars/dorift/02.jpg'
    ]
    channel = discord.utils.get()
    if channel == 705161333972140072:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(pictures)}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace with**

```
channel = bot.get_channel(705161333972140072)
if ctx.channel == channel:
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(pictures)}')
```

**Remove from your code**

```
channel = discord.utils.get()
if channel == 705161333972140072:
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(pictures)}')
```

Actually you were making a basic syntax error !

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could improve the quality of your answer with a few explanations (i.e. pointing out why your solutions works and why the one from the questioner doesn't).